# Dual boot with ubuntu 12.04 and 13.04

Tags: 12.04, grub2, dual-boot, 13.04, kernel

I have installed 13.04 on the resident 8GB memory in my Acer Aspire One netbook.
I have tried to install 12.04 (LTS) on the 32GB SD card.
On start-up Grub Shows Ubuntu at the top of the list and Ubuntu 12.04.2 as the 5th option.
Pressing for the first option boots into 13.04.
Pressing for 12.04 I get a second screen which says:

```
error: no such device: dc627e4-5758-4f80-9516-d2404193a780.
error: file '/boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-23-generic' not found.
error: you need to load the kernel first.

Press any key to continue..._
```

Pressing a key returns me to the first menu.

Any help in solving this would be appreciated.  The Acer is not my main computer and I wished to compare the two versions.  I do not (as yet) have any personal files on this computer and have reinstalled the two versions a couple of times to try to solve this problem without success.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the boot cannot find the device with the uuid dc627... Does it really exist? Look at the result of -

```
sudo blkid
```

to see the list of uuids for your devices. If the list does not include dc627..., just edit in the correct number in /boot/grub/grub.cfg, or run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Answer (score 0):

Press c for grub 1.9 menu. Write -

- GRUB> Linux /vmlinuz
- GRUB> root={hd0,1)
- GRUB> linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/sda1
- GRUB> initrd    /initrd.img
- GRUB> boot